# Does modulus overflow?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, integer-overflow

I know that (INT_MIN / -1) overflows, but (INT_MIN % -1) does not. At least this is what happens in two compilers, one pre-c++11 (VC++ 2010) and the other post-c++11 GCC 4.8.1

```
int x = INT_MIN;
cout << x / -1 << endl; 
cout << x % -1 << endl;
```

Gives:

```
-2147483648
0
```

Is this behavior standard defined or this is implementation defined? 
Also is there ANY OTHER case where the division operation would overflow?
and is there any case where the modulus operator would overflow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [CERT C++ Secure Coding Standard](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/VOID+INT32-CPP.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow) modulus can [can overflow](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/INT32-CPP.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow#INT32-CPP.Ensurethatoperationsonsignedintegersdonotresultinoverflow-Modulo) it says:

> [...]Overflow can occur during a modulo operation when the dividend is equal to the minimum (negative) value for the signed integer type and the divisor is equal to -1.

and they recommend the follow style of check to prevent overflow:

```
signed long sl1, sl2, result;

/* Initialize sl1 and sl2 */

if ( (sl2 == 0 ) || ( (sl1 == LONG_MIN) && (sl2 == -1) ) ) {
  /* handle error condition */
}
else {
  result = sl1 % sl2;
}
```

The [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.6` *Multiplicative operators* paragraph *4* says(*emphasis mine*):

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined. For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded;<sup>81</sup> **if the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result, (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a; otherwise, the behavior of both a/b and a%b is undefined.**

The [C version of the CERT document](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow#INT32-C.Ensurethatoperationsonsignedintegersdonotresultinoverflow-Modulo) provides some more insight on how `%` works on some platforms and in some cases `INT_MIN % -1` could produce a *floating-point exception*.

The logic for [preventing overflow for /](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/INT32-CPP.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow#INT32-CPP.Ensurethatoperationsonsignedintegersdonotresultinoverflow-Division) is the same as the above logic for `%`.

Comment: Are they adding the "otherwise" portion to the next standard?  The current C++11 standard does not include it (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf).

Comment: @ZacHowland It looks like the *otherwise* portion was added since `N3485`, all the drafts forward have the same language. This [previous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) has a nice collection of links to drafts.

Comment: @Pacerier it seems like they have moved the content so, maybe it was unavailable while that was going on. I fixed the linked.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the modulo operation that is causing an overflow:

```
int x = INT_MIN;
int a = x / -1; // int's are 2's complement, so this is effectively -INT_MIN which overflows
int b = x % -1; // there is never a non-0 result for a anything +/- 1 as there is no remainder
```

Answer (score 0):

Every modern implementation of the C++ language uses two's complement as the underlying representation scheme for integers. As a result, -INT_MIN is never representable as an int. (INT_MAX is -1+INT_MIN). There is overflow because the value x/-1 can't be represented as an int when x is INT_MIN.

Think about what % computes. If the result can be represented as an int, there won't be any overflow.

Comment: (OP's asking in C++, not C)

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. The reason is the same, so I edited to say C++.

Comment: This should say something like “every modern mainstream implementation”. Certainly there are odd implementations out there for peculiar or niche systems. And anybody can check out the GCC sources, modify the behavior to differ but still be conforming (to the extent GCC is to start with), and truthfully claim they have a C implementation that differs from your assertion.

Comment: True. Better yet, I might have said the observed overflow behavior suggests that "your C++ implementation, like all mainstream implementations, uses two's complement..."