# Does Java's % operator ever overflow?

Tags: java, operators, portability, modulo, strictfp

In C and C++, the behavior of  `INT_MIN % -1` seems to be undefined / platform-dependent as per [Shafik's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19285537/632951).

In Java, does the % operator ever overflow?

Consider this piece of code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // setup variables:
        byte b = Byte.MIN_VALUE % (-1);
        short s = Short.MIN_VALUE % (-1);
        int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE % (-1);
        long l = Long.MIN_VALUE % (-1);

        // my machine prints "0" for all:
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Is there a platform-independent guarantee that the above results are `0`?

Comment: Java in nature is platform independent so I guess (not checked) that the answer is YES

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [JLS section 15.17.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.17.3) it says:

> In C and C++, the remainder operator accepts only integral operands,
>   but in the Java programming language, it also accepts floating-point
>   operands.
>
> The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary
>   numeric promotion (§5.6.2) produces a result value such that
>   (a/b)*b+(a%b) is equal to a. This identity holds even in the special
>   case that the dividend is the negative integer of largest possible
>   magnitude for its type and the divisor is -1 (the remainder is 0). It
>   follows from this rule that the result of the remainder operation can
>   be negative only if the dividend is negative, and can be positive only
>   if the dividend is positive;

Comment: I was just about to post that ^^ Almost everything is in the JLS, especially for this kind of questions.

Comment: sorry @Joffrey i had that topic on my screen when i was reading that question :-$

Comment: Haha it's no problem, the point here is to get an answer to the question, no matter who writes it ;)

Comment: i do think the same - it's not so important who does it - it's more important WHAT has been submitted!